# Mock graphserviceclient to return a response

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, microsoft-graph-sdks

How can I mock the GraphServiceClient in the unit tests and return a mock response?

```
     private GraphServiceClient gsc;
    
     public RiskIQService(GraphServiceClient gsc)
     {
         gsc = gsc;
     }
    
     public string getRegistrar()
     {
            Microsoft.Graph.Models.Security.Hostname? response = (Microsoft.Graph.Models.Security.Hostname?) await gsc.Security.ThreatIntelligence.Hosts[domain].GetAsync();
    
         return response.Registrar;
     }
```

I was trying something similar to below, but see this error -     `System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: ... => ....GetAsync(null, CancellationToken.None) Non-overridable members (here: HostItemRequestBuilder.GetAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.`

```
private readonly Mock<GraphServiceClient> gscMock = new Mock<GraphServiceClient>();
var response = new Hostname(Registrar = "Registrar");
gscMock.Setup(x => x.Security.ThreatIntelligence.Hosts[It.IsAny<string>()].GetAsync(null, CancellationToken.None)).ReturnsAsync(response);
```

Comment: Mocking with the new Graph SDK isn't easy, but possible. Some different approaches can be found at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1746